# Why Current draw in DC variable power supply is not sizable?

Tags: capacitor, resistors, transformer, lm317, bridge-rectifier

I have done a DC variable power supply, and checked it using multimeter the output voltage ranges from 1.3v to 19v, but the problem is when I added a DC load(small DC motor) it was not working, why?
[image: Circuit diagram]
At No load, the output voltage ranges from 1.3v to 19v but, with load, voltage becomes zero.

DC motor specifications
Operating voltage - 3-6v
Current- 300 mA

Comment: By 'not working' what do you mean? What is it doing? Not outputting any voltage at all? Dropping voltage? What is the size of the DC load? How much current does your motor need, and how much can your power supply give? What was your output voltage when testing? What voltage does the motor need? What were you expecting to happen and what *did* happen? You need to add some more information to the question.

Comment: post a schematic of the DC variable power supply you 'have done'. If it uses a small package 317 for instance and a high input voltage, it might go into thermal limiting at quite low output current. Without details of what you have there, we just don't know, any guesswork will be totally uninformed.

Comment: I have posted the circuit diagram with my query. Please do have a look at it and clarify me

Comment: DC motor ratings operating voltage 3-6v current 300mA

Comment: At No load output voltage ranges from 1.3v to 19v but with load voltage becomes zero

Comment: At 2.2k, R1 is the reason your output becomes 0V with any load. Why do you have a 2.2k resistor in series with the input to your regulator?

Comment: K then, shall I remove that resistor or replace? In case of replacing, what should be the resistor value?

Comment: Remove it. But it was a mistake for it to be there, and you should explain where it came from.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out in the comments, the reason for this is the 2k2 resistor before the regulator. Because this is in series, any load will cause a voltage drop over it. A multimeter will use barely any current, hence you will see what appears to be a working circuit, however, even drawing just 10 mA will result in a voltage drop of 10*2.2 = 22V.

Remove this and your circuit should work fine.

Why it was added in the first place, I am unsure, my guesses would be perhaps for current measurement (because of the stated 1W), but had the value wrong, although even that would still have it placed incorrectly, it should be post regulator. The other thing is it could have been fitted wrong in the schematic and it was supposed to be in parallel with the smoothing capacitor to discharge it when powered off.

Either way, remove R1 and you should find your circuit works.

Comment: Perhaps the reason for R1 was to protect the diode bridge from the inrush current caused by C1, or something similar. The value is definitely off, though.

Comment: Yeah, that's another good theory. It could be any reason!

Comment: With your reference, I placed that 2.2k resistor in parallel to C1, the circuit work perfectly but after few minutes, the resistors dissipates too much of heat, Can you say me an alternate way or better shall I remove that resistor, if I remove that resistor will that circuit has longer life???

Comment: Any old resistor won't do, probably hence the 1W rating on it. The circuit will work fine without it. I was merely speculating what it could possibly have been used for

Comment: 2.2 Ohm would be a little more reasonable, especially considering the 1 W rating. Then it would work as an inrush current limiter/filter. Still a bit unusual.

Comment: K then, if I remove that 2.2k resistor the life of the circuit will be longer or not?

Comment: Well, if you leave it there, it won't work, so technically yes, the life will be longer. Just remove it and your circuit will work fine. I've used the LM317 in many circuits which have worked just fine!